# How can I get the name of a drive in python

Tags: python, windows, ctypes

I have a list of valid drive letters, and I want to present a choice to the end user. I'd like to show them the names of the drives. Here's some code that should show me the name of drive `F:\`:

```
import ctypes

kernel32 = ctypes.windll.kernel32
buf = ctypes.create_unicode_buffer(1024)

kernel32.GetVolumeNameForVolumeMountPointW(
    ctypes.c_wchar_p("F:\\"),
    buf,
    ctypes.sizeof(buf)
)

print buf.value
```

However, this outputs `\\?\Volume{a8b6b3df-1a63-11e1-9f6f-0007e9ebdfbf}\`. How can I get the string that windows shows in explorer (eg, `KINGSTON`, for a certain flash drive I own)?

---

#### EDIT:

Still not working:

```
volumeNameBuffer = ctypes.create_unicode_buffer(1024)
fileSystemNameBuffer = ctypes.create_unicode_buffer(1024)

kernel32.GetVolumeInformationW(
    ctypes.c_wchar_p("C:\\"),
    volumeNameBuffer,
    ctypes.sizeof(volumeNameBuffer),
    fileSystemNameBuffer,
    ctypes.sizeof(fileSystemNameBuffer)
)
```

This gives me this error:

```
WindowsError: exception: access violation reading 0x3A353FA0
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the [`GetVolumeInformation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364993%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function instead. It returns the volume label directly.

Comment: There are three other parameters you haven't passed: `lpVolumeSerialNumber`, `lpMaximumComponentLength`, and `lpFileSystemFlags`. The "optional" designation in the documentation doesn't mean that you can simply leave them out, but that you can pass `NULL` as a pointer to that information if you're not interested in the value.

Comment: @GregHewgill: Awesome. Thanks!

Answer (score 17):

Why don't you use `win32api.GetVolumeInformation` from the [`pywin32` module](https://pypi.org/project/pywin32/)?

```
import win32api
win32api.GetVolumeInformation("C:\\")
```

outputs

```
('WINDOWS', 1992293715, 255, 65470719, 'NTFS')
```

Answer (score 8):

Using the above fragment, I filled in the missing(optional, null) arguments as a quick helper:

```
import ctypes
kernel32 = ctypes.windll.kernel32
volumeNameBuffer = ctypes.create_unicode_buffer(1024)
fileSystemNameBuffer = ctypes.create_unicode_buffer(1024)
serial_number = None
max_component_length = None
file_system_flags = None

rc = kernel32.GetVolumeInformationW(
    ctypes.c_wchar_p("F:\\"),
    volumeNameBuffer,
    ctypes.sizeof(volumeNameBuffer),
    serial_number,
    max_component_length,
    file_system_flags,
    fileSystemNameBuffer,
    ctypes.sizeof(fileSystemNameBuffer)
)

print volumeNameBuffer.value
print fileSystemNameBuffer.value
```

This should be copy-and-paste-able.

Answer (score 2):

You can execute windows shell cmd and parse the output.

in Python 3.x:

```
import subprocess 
def getDriveName(driveletter):
    return subprocess.check_output(["cmd","/c vol "+driveletter]).decode().split("\r\n")[0].split(" ").pop()

print (getDriveName("d:"))
```

in Python 2.7:

```
import subprocess 
def getDriveName(driveletter):
    return subprocess.check_output(["cmd","/c vol "+driveletter]).split("\r\n")[0].split(" ").pop()

print getDriveName("d:")
```

Answer (score 1):

- returns driveLetter for the given driveLabel
- returns "notfound" if driveLabel was not found

def findDriveByDriveLabel(driveLabel):

```
drvArr = ['c:', 'd:', 'e:', 'f:', 'g:', 'h:', 'i:', 'j:', 'k:', 'l:']
for dl in drvArr:
    try:
        if (os.path.isdir(dl) != 0):
            val = subprocess.check_output(["cmd", "/c vol " + dl])
            if (driveLabel in str(val)):
                return dl + "/"
    except:
        print("Error: findDriveByDriveLabel(): exception")

return "notfound"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import win32api
import win32file
drives = win32api.GetLogicalDriveStrings()
drives =  drives.split('\000')[:-1]

for drive in drives:
    if win32file.GetDriveType(drive)==win32file.DRIVE_REMOVABLE:
        label,fs,serial,c,d = win32api.GetVolumeInformation(drive)
        print(label)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).